# How to fill background colors on line-charts?

Tags: plugins, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm migrating some plots from Plot.ly to Chart.js v2.9, and I'm trying to add background colors to my new Chart.js plots to match their predecessor:
[image]

But when I add the appropriate plugin to my Chart.js config, instead I get this:

[image]

Here is my plugin code:

```
 [{
  beforeDraw: function (chart, easing) {
    let config: DragenChartConfiguration = chart.config;
    if (chart.ctx) {
      if (config.dragen?.hBars) {
        var ctx = chart.ctx;
        var chartArea = chart.chartArea;

        for (const hBar of config.dragen.hBars) {
          ctx.save();
          ctx.fillStyle = hBar.color;
          ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, hBar.from, chartArea.right - chartArea.left, hBar.to - hBar.from);
          ctx.restore();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

Where each "Hbar" object simply defines a color and a Y-axis range I want to color:

```
hBars: Array(3)
0: {from: 28, to: 100, color: "rgb(195, 230, 195)"}
1: {from: 20, to: 28, color: "rgb(230, 220, 195)"}
2: {from: 0, to: 20, color: "rgb(230, 195, 195)"}
length: 3
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You are taking raw values instead of getting the pixels for those values, if you do that it will work:

Plugin V3:

```
{
  id: 'backgrounds',
  beforeDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
    const { ctx, chartArea, scales: {y} } = chart;
    
    options.hbars.forEach((hBar) => {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.fillStyle = hBar.color;
      ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, y.getPixelForValue(hBar.from), chartArea.right - chartArea.left, y.getPixelForValue(hBar.to) - y.getPixelForValue(hBar.from));
      ctx.restore();
    })
  }
}
```

Plugin V2:

```
{
  id: 'backgrounds',
  beforeDraw: (chart, x, options) => {
    const { ctx, chartArea, scales } = chart;
    const y = scales['y-axis-0']
    
    options.hbars.forEach((hBar) => {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.fillStyle = hBar.color;
      ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, y.getPixelForValue(hBar.from), chartArea.right - chartArea.left, y.getPixelForValue(hBar.to) - y.getPixelForValue(hBar.from));
      ctx.restore();
    }) 
  }
```

Working example V3:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [100, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      backgrounds: {
        hbars: [{
            from: 28,
            to: 100,
            color: "rgb(195, 230, 195)"
          },
          {
            from: 20,
            to: 28,
            color: "rgb(230, 220, 195)"
          },
          {
            from: 0,
            to: 20,
            color: "rgb(230, 195, 195)"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'backgrounds',
    beforeDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
      const {
        ctx,
        chartArea,
        scales: {
          y
        }
      } = chart;

      options.hbars.forEach((hBar) => {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = hBar.color;
        ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, y.getPixelForValue(hBar.from), chartArea.right - chartArea.left, y.getPixelForValue(hBar.to) - y.getPixelForValue(hBar.from));
        ctx.restore();
      })
    }
  }]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Working example V2:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [100, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      backgrounds: {
        hbars: [{
            from: 28,
            to: 100,
            color: "rgb(195, 230, 195)"
          },
          {
            from: 20,
            to: 28,
            color: "rgb(230, 220, 195)"
          },
          {
            from: 0,
            to: 20,
            color: "rgb(230, 195, 195)"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'backgrounds',
    beforeDraw: (chart, x, options) => {
      const {
        ctx,
        chartArea,
        scales
      } = chart;
      const y = scales['y-axis-0']

      options.hbars.forEach((hBar) => {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = hBar.color;
        ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, y.getPixelForValue(hBar.from), chartArea.right - chartArea.left, y.getPixelForValue(hBar.to) - y.getPixelForValue(hBar.from));
        ctx.restore();
      })
    }
  }]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Fiddle V3: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/6s8upz10/15/

Fiddle V2: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/tj71gLa2/10/

Comment: Thanks, but that appears to be a v3 specific solution.  How do I get the scales on Chart.js on v2?  (I'm stuck on v2.9.4 for compatibility with some plugins)

Comment: Updated answer with v2 syntax too @BioInfoBrett

Comment: Much obliged!  I will give it a try in the morning